# What movie has this virtual reality scene in it, of an office worker whose fantasy was to be a success at work?

Tags: story-identification, movie, virtual-worlds

It was one of those earlier movies that featured paying for a virtual reality experience/fantasy and this clip wasn't the main part of the movie, but rather an example of a fantasy you could get, or a brief flash into a fantasy that a back ground character was having.  It was a seemingly unsatisfied office worker having a fantasy about being a success at work, where everyone was cheering him on and praising him.  Any idea which movie had this clip in it?

Comment: There was a bit in *Minority Report* where something like this was going on in one of the hologram booths.  Not able to find a source clip quickly however.

Comment: Any other details you can think of? Where you watched this (country, medium)? What was the language? How old was it?

Comment: That clip in Minority Report is very similar, thank you - the fantasy I'm looking for was taking place in an more realized office setting though, and might be from a movie older than MR.  We saw it in English in the US in a theater.  I'm unsure of the date however.

Comment: @Markstarr - when did you see it?  That alone could help cut out a bunch of false positives like mine.

Answer (score 7):

[Minority Report](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0181689)

This scene, where a man in a commercial VR establishment fantasizes himself being congratulated by a group of people while feigning humbleness.
[image: Minority Report (2002)]

Comment: here is a youtube clip of the scene.  Really short. https://youtu.be/8tjOVOSqdQ0?t=24s

Comment: Oh good. I was vague because I didn't have the facilities to find a video, and it's been a few years since I've seen it